# run tests from msbuild script

Tags: mstest

Is there a sample script that runs tests in a solution from msbuild script. I am using MSBuild 4.4 and visual studio 2010.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unit tests are run with the [MSTest.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx) utility. You could [execute it from MSBuild](http://geekswithblogs.net/michaelstephenson/archive/2007/04/27/112031.aspx).

Comment: i run that command it showed that the 2 tests i have run and passed but before that success line threw this error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Qual
 ityTools.Tips.WebLoadTest.Tip, Version=10.0.0.0